# How to lookup django session for a particular user?

Tags: django, authentication, session

I am writing an application where I will be accessing the database from django and from a stand alone application. Both need to do session verification and the session should be the same for both of them. Django has a built in authentication/session verification, which is what I am using, now I need to figure out how to reuse the same session for my stand alone application.

My question is how can I look up a session_key for a particular user?

From what it looks there is nothing that ties together auth_user and django_session

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Modifying the `django_session` table to add an explicit `user_id` can make life a lot easier. Assuming you do that (or something similar), here are four approaches to munging things to your liking:

Fork the `django.contrib.session` code. I know, I know, that's a horrible thing to suggest. But it's only 500 lines including all backends and minus the tests. It's pretty straightforward to hack. This is the best route only if you are going to do some serious rearranging of things.

If you don't want to fork, you could try connecting to the `Session.post_save` signal and munge there.

Or you could MonkeyPatch `contrib.session.models.Session.save()`. Just wrap the existing method (or create a new one), breakout/synthesize whatever values you need, store them in your new fields, and then `super(Session, self).save()`.

Yet another way of doing this is to put in 2 (yes, two) middleware classes -- one before and one after `SessionMiddleware` in your *settings.py* file. This is because of the way middleware is processed. The one listed after `SessionMiddleware` will get, on the inbound request, a request with the session already attached to it. The one listed before can do any processing on the response and/or change/resave the session.

We used a variation on this last technique to create pseudo-sessions for search engine spiders to give them special access to material that is normally member-only. We also detect inbound links where the `REFERER` field is from the associated search engine and we give the user full access to that one article.

**Update:**

My answer is now quite ancient, although it still is mostly correct. See @Gavin_Ballard's much more recent answer (9/29/2014) below for yet another approach to this problem.

Comment: Doing this can break tests if you do it without forking the django code. If the sessions app is in the INSTALLED_APPS then the sessions table will be created twice causing the tests to abort. I'm not sure whether it is safe to remove the django session app if you've provided your own django_session table.

Comment: Django user sessions is now available to give you this functionality:  https://github.com/Bouke/django-user-sessions

Comment: @sww314 - I did a quick scan of the linked GitHub project, and it looks like a very reasonable approach to the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 62):

This answer is being posted five years after the original question, but this SO thread is one of the top Google results when searching for a solution to this problem (and it's still something that isn't supported out of the box with Django).

I've got an alternate solution for the use case where you're only concerned with logged in user sessions, which uses an additional `UserSession` model to map users to their sessions, something like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
```

Then you can simply save a new `UserSession` instance any time a user logs in:

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def user_logged_in_handler(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(user = user, session_id = request.session.session_key)

user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_handler)
```

And finally when you'd like to list (and potentially clear) the sessions for a particular user:

```
from .models import UserSession

def delete_user_sessions(user):
    user_sessions = UserSession.objects.filter(user = user)
    for user_session in user_sessions:
        user_session.session.delete()
```

That's the nuts and bolts of it, if you'd like more detail I have a [blog post](http://gavinballard.com/associating-django-users-sessions/) covering it.

Comment: The issue I'm having is that the session is not necessarily saved when `user_logged_in` fires, and so get a FK constraint error. Is it safe to run `request.session.save()` within `user_logged_in_handler()` first? Alternatively, I could change the FK field to text, but that means I'll probably need to do some extra cleanup.

Comment: Side question: What if I wanted to keep track of user's logins? Deleting the session I would lose that. How can I invalidate the session without deleting it?

Comment: @DanH I haven't seen that problem; rather than calling `request.session.save()` I think I'd go with your second option and avoid using a FK. The only extra cleanup you'd have to do is calling `user_session.delete()` after `user_session.session.delete()`. (In this example, you'd have to add a `session()` method to your `UserSession` model to look up the correct session.)

Comment: @alfetopito: You could simply alter the FK relation of the `UserSession` model to not `CASCADE` a deletion. You'd then keep a record of logins in the `UserSession` table, while still invalidating the sessions themselves.

Comment: @GavinBallard tks! I ended up using something similar to what you said. I stored the session_key in a CharField rather than as a ForeignKey, mostly to avoid DB Integrity exceptions since the session object is only saved after the view returns. Also, this way I can delete the session object without the cascading effect.

Comment: I ran into the same FK issue as @DanH, which seems like a logical issue to resolve. Removing the foreign key seems like it invalidates your otherwise elegant solution.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, another problem with this approach is that if you have very short sessions (say 30 minutes or one hour), it won't catch those users whose sessions have expired (since they didn't have an opportunity to log out).  Short sessions are necessary if you have a website that allows a user to see what other users are logged in.

Comment: @Robert: I'm not quite sure what you mean here. Even if a session has expired, it will still be mapped to the user via the `UserSession` model. If you have something cleaning up expired user sessions (eg a cron job) then yes, the mapping `UserSession` will also be removed - but that's generally desirable behaviour.

The primary goal of this is to be able to remove any remaining valid sessions for a user.

Comment: /admin/ gives the following error... user_logged_in_handler() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)     in the parameters i have replaced user by CustomUser as i have extended User models by AbstractUser.

Comment: You don't want a FK anyways as the session storage is pluggable,

Answer (score 33):

I found this code snippet

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

session_key = '8cae76c505f15432b48c8292a7dd0e54'

session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
uid = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)

print user.username, user.get_full_name(), user.email
```

here
http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/12/04/get-user-from-session-key-in-django/

Have not verified it yet, but looks pretty straight forward.

Comment: Straightforward, but the reverse operation. Obtaining the key from the user id (without modifying models) requires iterating over every session.

Comment: Upvoting, because google search for "django deserialize session" leads here.

Answer (score 28):

This is somewhat tricky to do, because not every session is necessarily associated with an authenticated user; Django's session framework supports anonymous sessions as well, and anyone who visits your site will have a session, regardless of whether they're logged in.

This is made trickier still by the fact that the session object itself is serialized -- since Django has no way of knowing which data exactly you want to store, it simply serializes the dictionary of session data into a string (using Python's standard "pickle" module) and stuffs that into your database.

If you have the session key (which will be sent by the user's browser as the cookie value "sessionid"), the easiest way to get at the data is simply to query the Session table for the session with that key, which returns a Session object. You can then call that object's "get_decoded()" method to get the dictionary of session data. If you're not using Django, you can look at the source code (django/contrib/sessions/models.py) to see how the session data is deserialized.

If you have the user id, however, you'll need to loop through all of the Session objects, deserializing each one and looking for one which has a key named "_auth_user_id", and for which the value of that key is the user id.

Comment: and why not attached the session to a user in a middleware, and not to the request as in the built-in version?

Answer (score 7):

Peter Rowell, thanks for your response.  It was a tremendous help.  This is what I did to get it working.  Only had to change one file in djang.contrib.sessions.

In django/contrib/sessions/models.py, add the user_id to the table (add to DB table manually or drop table and run manage.py syncdb).

```
class Session(models.Model):

    ...

    user_id = models.IntegerField(_('user_id'), null=True)

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = self.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
        if ( user_id != None ):
            self.user_id = user_id

        # Call the "real" save() method.
        super(Session, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now in your view where you do login (if you use django's base login, you will have to override it)

```
# On login, destroy all prev sessions
        # This disallows multiple logins from different browsers
        dbSessions = Session.objects.filter( user_id = request.user.id )
        for index, dbSession in enumerate( dbSessions ):
            if ( dbSession.session_key != request.session.session_key ):
                dbSession.delete()
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This is not really a good solution as it requires you to make changes in the core django code.

Answer (score 7):

I ran across this problem when I wanted to kick out a spammer.  It seems setting their account to "inactive" isn't enough, because they can still come in on their previous session. So - how to delete a session for a specific user, or how to deliberately expire a session for a specific user?

The answer is to user the `last_login` field to track down the time at which the session was disabled, which tells you that the `expire_date` is two weeks later, which lets you perform a useful filter on the sessions table:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

baduser = User.objects.get(username="whoever")     
two_weeks = relativedelta(weeks=2)
two_hours = relativedelta(hours=2)
expiry = baduser.last_login + two_weeks
sessions = Session.objects.filter(
    expire_date__gt=expiry - two_hours,
    expire_date__lt=expiry + two_hours
) 
print sessions.count() # hopefully a manageable number

for s in sessions:
    if s.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id') == baduser.id:
        print(s)
        s.delete()
```

Comment: Hacky but effective, I love it!  Unfortunately I think this doesn't work when the session backend is redis instead of the DB.