# How can i access the current user outside a request in django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a medium sized project in django and i want to be able to access the current user from within my query manager.  I need to be able to design a custom manager to limit the results and querysets so that the current user only get's information related to him/her.

I've received a few suggestions, I've also seen the not so supported example of using threadlocals from a django middleware. However, i'm very confused as this seems to be most promising solution now. I am looking for a better way to do this, so i can gain access to the current user from within a model manager.

Comment: What is a current user outside a request? Many people can use the system at the same time?

Comment: Why can't you pass it from your view to your manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can store the user object  in the session object and get it out when needed

refer to [how-to-lookup-django-session-for-a-particular-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235950/how-to-lookup-django-session-for-a-particular-user)

Answer (score 3):

There is no sane way to get the user outside of the request. If the current user matters then pass it to any functions that need it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to save current user as a foreign key is that override save_model method that is like:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """
        Given a model instance save it to the database.
        """
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
```