# Django Storing A List of Logged In Users

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on a login system in a Django app and I was wondering about how should I check if a user is logged in across all sessions.

Logically speaking, if a user is logged in in, let's say, Browser #1, and is trying to log in from another place, Browser #2, should I just let them log in? Or should I also force log them out from the other place they were logged in (Browser #1)?

Regardless the answer for my 1st question, what's the best way to store all logged in users or how to force log a user out from it's previous log in browser?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you determine when a user is still logged in?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure but thinks that's part of my question. Like, I an determine if a user is logged in by just `if request.user.is_authenticated()` but that's not the case (right?).

Comment: That's how you determine if the *current* user is logged in. But what about if they log in on browser 1 but just keep the page open? Are they still logged in?

Comment: Currently, they're considered logged in until they log out.

Comment: The most informative you have is active sessions. There is no direct db relation between users and sessions by default in django, but you can create such a relation. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235950/how-to-lookup-django-session-for-a-particular-user) e.g. Whether the cookies of your active sessions are still set in any browser out there is another question though.

Comment: try with this Django tool: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-user-sessions