# Django: Get user's previous anonymous session key on login

Tags: django, session

In a `django` app, I'm trying to associate sessions for anonymous users to the new logged-in session for that user when the user logs in. In other words, on login I want to figure out the session key that existed for that user up until the moment they logged in.

I realize I won't be able to get all previous anonymous uses from sessions that have expired, I'm only interested in the just-expired session_key that was used for the user up until the point they logged in and `cycle_key()` is called.

I'm doing something similar to [How to lookup django session for a particular user?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26097566) but this only gives me the *active* session key, and I also want to access the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option that you have is rewrite default `SessionMiddleware` for your needs https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py

See the last part where the cookie is set.

Comment: I ended up writing my own middleware for this that captures the key (if any) in `process_request()` and adds it to the request object, and then compares the saved key to the key in the request object in `process_response()` and handles it accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @seawolf any chance you could share your middle ware?

Comment: This is what I came up with, not brilliant and I'm not sure it's exactly what I want but it does the trick: https://github.com/seawolf42/django-autometrics/blob/master/autometrics_nonrel/middleware.py