# How to force logout a user from another app?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm writing a django project that will act as FreeRadius backend (via it's rlm_rest)

It's specificaly for captive portal login. I also use allauth with this project.

Basically, user have to login to my site first before the captive portal send radius request.

Currently, it's just work.

But (yes there is a 'but')
When the user logout from captive portal, captive portal just kick them out from it, and tell radius that the user logged out.

When the portal tell radius, radius will call my project  to book that event ... just like normal radius-acct.

So ...
Is there any way for me to check all session belonging to that user and flush it?

Comment: You can't query the `Session` table for all sessions of a particular user, because the session first needs to be decoded before you can access its user info (the `_auth_user_id` key). So the best way would be to keep track of user's session id at login, in a separate table, so that when radius tells you "this user has logged out", you can easily retrieve that session and expire/delete it.

Comment: Look also at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235950/how-to-lookup-django-session-for-a-particular-user) for a more thorough discussion